# What home chemical can I use to make droplet lens?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, optical-properties

I'm very interested in making homemade droplet lens, I want to know what home element can I use to cook them.

Here's a video showing the process, with no further information:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQLWS5j8gB4

And a research paper about it:

http://www.opticsinfobase.org/boe/fulltext.cfm?uri=boe-5-5-1626&id=284161

Comment: The paper says it's just PDMS, I doubt there are any home substitutes that would work very well. Silicone caulk, perhaps? Most of those don't cure transparent enough, I don't think, though.

Comment: There are a bunch of thermoplastics that are crystal clear when solid.  Getting them to form a nice drop like this might be a challenge though.  To get the same effect you can use the lens from a laser pointer.